# Create multiple Python dictionaries from XML file

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I have a XML File which looks something like this:

```
<DATA>
    <DATA_VALUES>
        <SPEC>
            <Meta>1</Meta>
            <Data>100.430000</Data>
            <Intensity>2950.909708</Intensity>
            <Data>102.269997</Data>
            <Intensity>114341.550674</Intensity>
            <Data>103.260002</Data>
            <Intensity>47164.957890</Intensity>
            <Data>104.260002</Data>
            <Intensity>5102.098056</Intensity>
        </SPEC>
        <SPEC>
            <Peak>1</Peak>
            <Data>100.430000</Data>
            <Intensity>2950.909708</Intensity>
            <Data>102.269997</Data>
            <Intensity>114341.550674</Intensity>
            <Data>103.260002</Data>
            <Intensity>47164.957890</Intensity>
            <Data>104.260002</Data>
            <Intensity>5102.098056</Intensity>
        </SPEC>
```

There are actually many more  sections, I want to generate a dictionary for each  section with Data as Key and Intensity as Value.

I parse the XML file as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('File')
root = tree.getroot()

Data_Lst = []
Intensity_Lst = []
count = 0

for Data in root.iter('Data'):
    Data_Lst.append(Data.text)

for Intensity in root.iter('Intensity'):
    Intensity_Lst.append(Intensity.text)
    count += 1
    if count == len(Data_Lst):
       break

print(Data_Lst, Intensity_Lst)
```

I added the Count because the Intensity List is longer as the Data List.

Any ideas how I can generate the dicts for each  sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't iterate over the `Data` and `Intensity` nodes separately. If they don't match (and you said they don't) you will run out of sync quite fast.

Instead, iterate over the `SPEC` nodes and then search for the relative `Data` and `Intensity` nodes. Also notice I'm using `zip`, so in case there is a mismatch inside a `SPEC` node, the dict creation will stop when we consume the shorter list.

```
tree = ET.parse('File')
root = tree.getroot()

for spec_node in root.iter('SPEC'):
    d = dict(zip((data_node.text for data_node in spec_node.iter('Data')),
                 (intensity_node.text for intensity_node in spec_node.iter('Intensity'))))
    print(d)
```

For the above file this outputs

```
{'100.430000': '2950.909708', '102.269997': '114341.550674', '103.260002': '47164.957890',
 '104.260002': '5102.098056'}
{'100.430000': '2950.909708', '102.269997': '114341.550674', '103.260002': '47164.957890',
 '104.260002': '5102.098056'}
```

Note that `.text` returns string. If you need floats then use `float(node.text)` where applicable.

For example, in case of a mismatch:

```
<DATA>
    <DATA_VALUES>
        <SPEC>
            <Meta>1</Meta>
            <Data>1</Data>
            <Intensity>2</Intensity>
            <Data>3</Data>
            <Intensity>4</Intensity>
            <Data>5</Data>
            <Intensity>6</Intensity>
            <Data>7</Data>
            <Intensity>8</Intensity>
            <Data>9</Data>   <!-- This will not be in the dict -->
        </SPEC>
    </DATA_VALUES>
</DATA>
```

The created dictionary will be

```
{'1': '2', '3': '4', '5': '6', '7': '8'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and explicit answer, it works perfect for my File except that it also generates empty dicts, is there a way to delete them?

Comment: @bimarian The dict will be empty if a `SPEC` node does not contain a `Data` or `Intensity` nodes. You can simply ignore empty dicts by checking `if d:` which will be `True` if `d` is **not** empty